# Html validation on obsolete attribute to the <div> element

Tags: html, css, validation

I am validating my html and I'm trying to fix:

```
Error: The align attribute on the div element is obsolete
```

And have tried using

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
```

But When removing the previous `<div align="center">` and adding this new code, everything floats to the left of the viewport.

The use of this div is to center all content inside it, which contains nav bars, images, text etc.

What else can I try adding to align all this content and remove the mark-up error?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: You have to add the style to the parent of the div if you want the div to be centered in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, this helps!

```
div{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this one helped a lot! does this apply to all <div> elements?

Comment: Yes, if you want to apply for specific div apply this css to particular class or id

Answer (score 0):

Try aligning it in CSS

For example:
HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">My contents</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute "align" that you were using is no longer present in HTML5. Use CSS instead: style="text-align:center;" for an inline CSS.